# How to improve X cursors in a minimal ubuntu inside docker?

Tags: ubuntu, themes, xorg, cursors

I'm running ubuntu15.10 using the ubuntu image from the docker hub. Its a minimal ubuntu with almost nothing. I have installed ratpoison, xorg and xterm and a simple vnc server.

I can access the graphical interface of the container using vnc or forwarding the X protocol.

However, the cursor theme is the typical default cursor theme in Xorg, since I don't have unity or gnome or anything like that. I would like to change the cursor theme to something a bit more modern.

However, I only find instructions specific for unity, or for specific desktops.

¿It is possible to change the X cursor theme in a minimal Xorg installation in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
 -v /usr/share/icons:/usr/share/icons:ro
```

To your docker run command to get the same cursor as the host.